# JSON Parsing Error Microsoft Emotion API ios

Tags: ios, iphone, json, azure-cognitive-services

> I am having problem in using the Microsoft Emotion API i have read the [documentation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa) but not able to use it. Whenever i use the below code it gives Bad body JSON parsing error. I am not able to detect whats the problem in code.

i have created a method 
- (IBAction)clickToGenerateEmotion:(id)sender

```
NSString* path = @"https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize";
NSArray* array = @[
                    @"entities=true",
                   ];

NSString* string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", string];

NSLog(@"%@", path);

UIImage *yourImage= _image;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

NSMutableURLRequest* _request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[_request setValue:@"9b118d1587ce40899598b48a6c29b51a" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"];

 NSDictionary *params = @{@"\"url\"" : @"\"http://engineering.unl.edu/images/staff/Kayla_Person-small.jpg\""};

  NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *key in params) {
     [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, params[key]]];
   }

NSString *requestParams = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];


[_request setHTTPBody:imageData];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData* _connectionData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"responseData = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_connectionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
if (nil != error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary* json = nil;
    NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_connectionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataString);

    if (nil != _connectionData)
    {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_connectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }

    if (error || !json)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not parse loaded json with error:%@", error);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", json);
    _connectionData = nil;
}
`
```

## Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: First of all, try to check whether the response returns a VALID JSON OBJECT or NOT. If it's valid JSon, then we can check the code part!

Comment: i have checked in there testing console everything is working fine but its not working in code @RashmiRanjanmallick

Comment: I don't have a OSX machine handy, but my guess is that you need to declare `json` as a `NSArray`.